# Flask Pagination - Filter - Search Option - Please need support

Tags: flask, search, filter, pagination

I am pretty new in the world of programming with python, especially using flask for my current WebApp project:-)

Currently, I am trying to combine the pagination functionality with a filtering option which works perfectly for the first page :-( The filter value gets lost every time, when I change from e.g. page 1 to page 2.

How could you prevent the value from not being lost using different radios?

Attached are the relevant code sections for your review:

```
@data.route('/search', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def search():
    radios = request.form.get('size')
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type = int)
    articles = Data.query.order_by(Data.id.desc()).paginate(page = page, per_page = 5) 
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'number' in request.form and radios == 'size_1':
         number = request.form['number']
         search = "%{}%".format(number)
         articles = Data.query.filter(Data.sizes.like(search)).paginate(page = page, per_page=7)
    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'number' in request.form and radios == 'size_2':
     ...
     ...
     ...
    return render_template('search.html',articles = articles)
```

----HTML_Pagination----

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center" style="margin: 3px; padding-top: 30px; text-align: center;">
<div class="col-12">
    {% if articles.iter_pages(articles.total < 10) %} 
        {% for page_num in articles.iter_pages() %} 
            {% if page_num %} 
                {% if articles.page == page_num %} 
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" style="font-size: 10px;"
                    href="{{ url_for('data.search', page = page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-3" style="font-size: 10px;"
                        href="{{ url_for('data.search', page = page_num)}}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                ...
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for page_num in articles.iter_pages(left_edge = 2, right_edge = 2, left_current = 2, right_current = 2) %}
            {% if page_num %}
                {% if articles.page == page_num %}
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" style="font-size: 10px;"
                    href="{{ url_for('data.search', page = page_num)}}">{{ page_num}}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary mb-3" style="font-size: 10px;"
                    href="{{ url_for('data.search', page = page_num)}}">{{ page_num}}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            ...
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

----HTML----
---Radio & Input---

```
   <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="size" id="size" value="size_1">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="size">
           Size 1
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="size" id="size" value="size_2">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="size">
           Size 2
       </label>
   </div>
   ...
   ...
   <div class="col-6" style="text-align: right;">
       <div class="col-12" style="padding-right: 10px;">
           <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="number" id="number" value="{{ request.form['number'] }}" placeholder="Filter by...">
       </div>        
   </div>
```

---Submit Button---

```
<div class="col-4" style="padding-left: 20px;">
     <div class="col-md-auto" style=" padding-bottom: 15px;">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example">
                        {{ filter_articles.submit(class="btn btn-outline-secondary", style="font-size: 14.5px; ") }}
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Any guide is highly appreciated. Thank you!